# Audio files multiple upload not working with php

Tags: php, materialize

I created the PHP form below to send mp3 files to a database.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="audioForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row audiosRow">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn btn-small">
                        <span>Track</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload audio files* (.mp3)" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn btn-small">
                        <span>Track</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload audio files* (.mp3)" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn btn-small">
                        <span>Track</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload audio files* (.mp3)" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn btn-small">
                        <span>Track</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file-4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload audio files* (.mp3)" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="file-field input-field">
                    <div class="btn btn-small">
                        <span>Track</span>
                        <input type="file" name="file-5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload audio files* (.mp3)" readonly="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <button class="btn btn-small" type="submit" name="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The form works fine when I send images, but when I send audio files, it doesn't work with three or more. When I make a `var_dump($_FILES)` it displays `array(0){}`.

So I think it's probably a limitation, but I don't see that anywhere. I checked the php.ini configuration file, I have `upload_max_filesize = 200M` and `max_file_uploads = 20`.

So where can the problem be? Please help me.

Comment: try to print `var_dump($_FILES)` and analyse the results.

Comment: Why are you expecting data in $_POST? As any PHP file upload tutorial will show you, uploaded file data in PHP appears in $_FILES instead.

Comment: @HarishST that's a mistake. I did inspect $_FILES. I made a mistake when I was writing the post. Sorry. I have corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw where the problem was. `post_max_size` was limited to `8`. It had to be reduced to 0 `post_max_size=0` to make it unlimited. See the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: It is better to add some predefined-limit to the `post_max_size` configuration. Thus, you can prevent the bandwidth and memory from wasted if upload is available to public.

Comment: Okay thanks @HarishST I figured I'd have to do it. I will do that. Big Thanks